# Good way to get good looking bold circle with a letter over it

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, letters, circles, number

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=10] {\strut #1};}

\begin{document}
 $   \encircle{1}^A  $
\end{document}
```

This gives :

[image]

I want to get :

[image]

Comment: it is hard to guess exactly what you want. Please provide the bigger picture, even with hand drawing!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly like your example, but see if it's of any interest. The `dash pattern` is also a bit of a hack, that won't work well in all cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\encircle[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw,
               line width=3pt,
               draw=blue,
               text=red,
               postaction={draw=red,dash pattern=on 4.1pt off 4pt},
               shape=circle,
               inner sep=2,
               label={[blue]above:#2}] {\strut #1};}

\begin{document}
 $   \encircle{1}{A}  $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\def\usestackanchor{T}%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcounter{index}
\def\dtheta{45}% degrees per dot
\def\dR{.44}% radius of circle in ex's
\def\dotsize{.55}% size of dots relative to period
\def\charwidth{3}% overall characterwidth in circle radii
\newlength\dRlen
\setlength\dRlen{\dR ex}
\def\basechar{\strut%
  \rule[.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox]{\charwidth\dRlen}{0ex}}
\savestack{\dotcircle}{\basechar}
\setcounter{index}{0}
\whiledo{\theindex<360}{%
  \FPdiv\thetaRad{\theindex}{57.29578}%
  \FPcos\dx{\thetaRad}%
  \FPmul\dx{\dR}{\dx}%
  \FPsin\dy{\thetaRad}%
  \FPmul\dy{\dR}{\dy}%
  \savestack{\dotcircle}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{\dy ex}{%
    \kern\dx ex\kern\dx ex\scalebox{\dotsize}{.}}{\dotcircle}}
  \addtocounter{index}{\dtheta}%
}
\newcommand\blivet{%
  \stackon[-3pt]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textcolor{red}{%
  \scalebox{.25}{1}}}{\stackengine{-.27pt}{\textcolor{cyan}{%
  \scalebox{1}[.95]{\textsf{o}}}}{\dotcircle}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}{%
  \textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{.25}{A}}}%
}
\begin{document}
x\blivet y
\end{document}
```

[image]